# Coldfusion 9 - respool mail

Tags: email, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, spool

I had a bunch of mail to be sent out that was not. I realized that my mail settings in Coldfusion Administrator were incorrect and have since corrected them. I tested the new settings with new mail and they work. I am now trying to re-send out the messages in the spool, but they go right back in the undelivered mail spool. I'm assuming that they are still using the old mail settings. Is there any way to force them to send out using the new current settings?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to edit the individual spool files, as they most likely have the mail server information in the file itself. If you open a few of the files in your badmail directory, you should be able to locate the server information and adjust accordingly.

If you can do a bulk find/replace on the files, it should make short work of it.

Comment: The changes that we had to implement to get it working was a different mail server, and adding a username and password. I sent an email that went through as it should. I then sent another one, but purposely put in the incorrect mail server so that it would go to the undelivered folder. I went in the delivered folder and put in the correct server name. I then went to respool and in the logs got:"javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses; nested exception is: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.7.1 <[server name][server ip address]>: Client host rejected: Access denied".